# Can I automate inserting password of PEM file for SSL certificates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ssl, pem

Whenever my server goes down, I need to login and manually restart MySQL so I can type in the password to the PEM file.

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: You can remove the pass phrase from the private key :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `openssl` to remove the pass phrase of your private key:

```
cp mysql.key mysql.key.orig
openssl rsa -in mysql.key.orig -out mysql.key
```

You will be asked for the pass phrase; afterwards, the key can be used without having to enter a password.

Comment: Is the only security risk that if someone gets a hold of the pem, they can impersonate my website?

Comment: @Nik yeah that would be the problem with it :)

Comment: Thank you.  I'll have to weight the security concerns.  Unfortunately, my host doesn't alert me when the server hosting my vps goes down, so I either need to get an alert, or figure out how to give myself an alert.  Unfortunately, their alerting services are pretty dismal/nonexistant.